# Is it possible to create a message in a Microsoft Teams Channel via Graph API using an Adaptive Card format (seems limited to Text and HTML)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm attempting to create a message in a Teams channel via the Graph API. Teams now supports adaptive cards but it seems we are still limited to either plain text or HTML when creating the message via Graph API (either v1 or beta). Anyone found a way to create this message using Adaptive Cards?
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/itembody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via Microsoft Graph, no, not yet. But via the Bot Framework APIs, yes, and it's available today.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards#cards-in-bots

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any rough timeline for Graph support? I have an existing SPA application which is already utilising the Graph API. Plumbing the Bot Framework in to get Adaptive card support is architecturally a step too far at this stage and it appears the vision is to light this up in the Graph API so I'll have to wait.

Comment: Is this still a valid answer? I can create a message with a thumbnail card but I didn't managed to do it with an adaptive card yet